# object isn't recognized anymore when my screen is in fully expanded modus

Tags: hp-uft

I have following problem. After spying an object my object isn't highlighting anymore within the application. However I noticed the following: when my application is in fully expanded modus, the object isn't highlighted and when my application is not in fully expanded modus the object is highligted (so recognized)! Even spying in expanded or not expanded modus, the object is only highlighting in not fully expanded modus. Problem is when running the script, it's open my appliation it seems in fully expanded modus.
Anybody an idea how this can be solved? Are there for example properties in the object I can set that it will not take care about fully or not fully expanded mode?

display settings is 100%
browser is chrome
version is UFT 14.51

Answer (score 0):

Founded. The zoom in the chrome browser must also set on 100%. Was 110%